# How to get value from modal in different input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have to make an interface management articles on which I have several buttons, which, upon clicking,  throws a dialog (modal). So far, everything is OK.

In the modal I have a value in the drop-down list. When I click "Save" I manage to display the selected element in the first 'input', but for the other buttons it does not work.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("[id^=btn_]").on('click', function(){
                var boutton_selectionne = this.id
                console.log(boutton_selectionne)
                $("#monModal").modal('show')
            })
            $('#sauvegarder').on('click', function(){
                var btn1 = $('#nbre_compart option:selected').text()
                $('#txt_btn1').val(btn1)
                return
            })   
        });
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <button class="btn btn-info" id="btn_mdl1">Boutton 1</button>
    <input type="text" name="btn_1" id="txt_btn1">
    <button class="btn btn-info" id="btn_mdl2">Boutton 2</button>
    <input type="text" name="btn_2" id="txt_btn2">
    <button class="btn btn-info" id="btn_mdl3">Boutton 3</button>
    <input type="text" name="btn_3" id="txt_btn3">
    <button class="btn btn-info" id="btn_mdl4">Boutton 4</button>
    <input type="text" name="btn_4" id="txt_btn4">
<div id="monModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <label for="nbre_compart">Nombre de compartiments</label>
                    <select id="nbre_compart">
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="6" selected>6</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                        </select> 
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="sauvegarder" class="btn btn-primary">Sauvegarder</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: your question is not clear, please explain it properly, what are you doing here and your expected output?

Comment: Here I have 4 buttons, and for each button there is an input text, when I click on the first button he show me the modal with a select value, and when I click on save or "Sauvegarder" the selected element must be showed on the input near button clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi now other buttons are working :), 
Libraries was not present in your code  that why its giving error on  model function.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("[id^=btn_]").on('click', function(){
                var boutton_selectionne = this.id
                console.log(boutton_selectionne);
               $('#sauvegarder').attr("data-id",this.id);
                $("#monModal").modal('show');
            })
            $('#sauvegarder').on('click', function(){
           

console.log("daf"+$('#sauvegarder').attr("data-id")); 

 var btn1 = $('#nbre_compart option:selected').text();
                $('#'+'txt_'+$('#sauvegarder').attr("data-id")).val(btn1)
                return
            })   
        });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
<body>
    <button class="btn btn-info" id="btn_mdl1">Boutton 1</button>
    <input type="text" name="btn_1" id="txt_btn_mdl1">
    <button class="btn btn-info" id="btn_mdl2">Boutton 2</button>
    <input type="text" name="btn_2" id="txt_btn_mdl2">
    <button class="btn btn-info" id="btn_mdl3">Boutton 3</button>
    <input type="text" name="btn_3" id="txt_btn_mdl3">
    <button class="btn btn-info" id="btn_mdl4">Boutton 4</button>
    <input type="text" name="btn_4" id="txt_btn_mdl4">
<div id="monModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <label for="nbre_compart">Nombre de compartiments</label>
                    <select id="nbre_compart">
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="6" selected>6</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                        </select> 
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="sauvegarder" class="btn btn-primary">Sauvegarder</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replay, but the problem is when I click on any button the result is sent to the first input